# how can I render conditional props using typescript and react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I can't seem to access the props shape

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/508357248330760249/831773180162998292/Untitled.png

Comment: Please include the actual code in the question, not pictures. And include the specific error message you're getting

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript is raising that error because that property is defined only for `shape: 'circle'`, so you have to narrow its type by matching the tag, in this case the `shape` property.

Example:

```
type ButtonProps = { fullName: string } & (
  | { shape: 'circle'; radius: number }
  | { shape: 'square'; width: number }
)
declare const props: ButtonProps

props.radius // Property 'radius' does not exist on type 'ButtonProps'

if (props.shape === 'circle') {
  props.radius // number
}
```

See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions.